# inconsistent tmux new-window behavior

Tags: tmux

I just installed tmux on my new MacBook Pro, and am running into the following issue.

When I create a new window via the command `tmux new-window` I get a new window with the same working directory as the session I'm creating from.  This is the behavior I expect/desire.

When I create a new window using C-b C-c, I get a new window in my home directory.

Why are my shortcut keys giving me different behavior/how do I make them use the same directory?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since Tmux 1.9 you should use the -c option in order to open a new working directory of the current pane.

```
tmux new-window -c '#{pane_current_path}'
```

Add this to your tmux.conf:

> bind c new-window -c '#{pane_current_path}'

Note: It is also possible that you will have to exit all running instances of the TMUX server before any changes to the `.tmux.conf` file will be loaded.

Comment: This is supported in tmux 1.9 onwards.

Comment: Yep! I forgot to mentiont that :D

Comment: If you have a slow Bash initialization, -c option may be not working. See http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tickets/115/

Answer (score 9):

If you also want split windows in the current directory, you can add this to tmux.conf:

```
bind "\"" split-window -c '#{pane_current_path}'
bind "\%" split-window -h -c '#{pane_current_path}'
```

Answer (score -1):

The quotes should not be in `tmux.conf`; at least not for tmux 2.1:

```
#
# open split panes in the current directory
#
bind-key \" split-window -c '#{pane_current_path}'
bind-key \% split-window -h -c '#{pane_current_path}'
```